# Visual Studio 2008 local debugging permission problems

Tags: visual-studio-2008, permissions

local debugging on a machine, ive set access to network service and everyone to full permission but every time im getting

Access to the path 'C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\Directory\pictures' is denied.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\Directory\pictures' is denied.

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.

To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

there is no {MACHINE}\ASPNET account, and ive tried impersonating my user account to no joy, and IUSR_MACHINENAME doesnt seem to be an account for my machine, any ideas?

code:

Dim newFile As FileStream = New FileStream(Server.MapPath("../pictures"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate)

Answer (score 0):

This could be a misleading error, stop IIS, then delete C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\[your version of framework]\Temporary ASP.NET Files, then restart IIS.

Also, when you're debugging, the application runs under the currently logged on user (you), not as NETWORK SERVICE, if you've been able to change the permissions on that folder I assume your account has full r+w rights, but just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an ancient question, but I just had this same issue, and i solved it by blowing away the bin folder for debugging.  VS then recompiled without a problem.